# Jenkins Git plugin and Refspecs

Tags: git, jenkins

What is the difference between **Refspec** and **Branch specifier (blank for default)**: in the below Jenkins job configuration:

[image]

I have tried to set the Refspec option in the job configuration:

```
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

In the cloned repo on my build slave the .git/config file looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://user:pass@git.internal.com/scm/PROJECT/project.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

It seems that the value for **fetch** is not correct (read from the jenkins job configuration). Further it has no effect on the diskspace consumption.

Comment: Obviously, the config of the repository is not affected. I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior or not but it should be noted that it is not strictly required since the refspec can afaik also be included in the git fetch command. Thus, you should try to check which command **really** gets executed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Refspec** defines options for the **fetch** operation (see [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359891/jenkins-configuration)) whereas the **branch specifier** defines which branch contains the code to be **built** by Jenkins. In other words: **Refspec** only defines how the code is retrieved while **branch specifier** which part of the code is going to be compiled.

[Edit:] Fixed broken link to refspec

Comment: Ok so if I only need to build eg. **my-feature** branch would it make sense to set refspec to **my-feature**? Would that save some space instead of fetching the complete repository/all branches?

Comment: Well, in principle that's true but keep in mind that git does a really good job in keeping branches lightweight. That is, git only saves differences and thus the overhead of fetching multiple branches will only be significant if the branches are **extremely** different form each other

Comment: It has no effect on diskspace consumption, but it seems that the option is never set - see edited post.

Comment: The git-scm link is dead now. I couldn't find a replacement though.