# Jenkins says it can't find Git branch, but it clearly exists

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I created a new pipeline for testing purposes to build a feature branch.

Git branch: feature/show-percentage-of-completion Script path: Jenkinsfile-cirrus-dev-feature Lightweight checkout: Not checked

When I run the build, I get this error below:

```
    Started by user woodsman1@mycompany.com
    Checking out git git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator.git into /jenkins_data/jenkins_home/jobs/cirrus-bluecost-ssc-cost-file-generator-dev-feature/workspace@script to read Jenkinsfile-cirrus-dev-feature
    The recommended git tool is: git
    using credential bluecost_git
     > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /jenkins_data/jenkins_home/jobs/cirrus-bluecost-ssc-cost-file-generator-dev-feature/workspace@script/.git # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     > git config remote.origin.url git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator.git # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
     > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
    using GIT_SSH to set credentials Bluecost (dpydalsprd101.sl.bluecloud.mycompany.com, /home/bluecost/.ssh )
     > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-bluecost-ssc-file-generator.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
     > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/feature/show-percentage-of-completion^{commit} # timeout=10
     > git rev-parse origin/feature/show-percentage-of-completion^{commit} # timeout=10
    ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
    ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
    Finished: FAILURE
```

What I don't understand about Jenkins is that I give it a repo and a branch name. Does it do git clone my-repo and then git checkout my-branch? No, it have to do this weird git --version, git --version ; git fetch; git rev-parse; git rev-parse. I have no idea why they found a set of cryptic steps to do this.

Also, I've verified both the repository and the branch exist. If I switched to the test branch, it would work. Why?

PS: a comment was made about checking the ref/spec. I wasn't sure where the commenter was referring, but I noticed this exists in the .git/config file as follows:

```
[branch "feature/show-percentage-of-completion"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/feature/show-percentage-of-completion
```

[image]

Comment: I refer to the field you see in https://stackoverflow.com/q/15447661/6309

Comment: That screenshot does not show the refspec field (which should be right above it)

Comment: In your repo, is `feature/show-percentage-of-completion` a branch or a tag ? Is it listed in `git branch` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec), as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15447661/6309).
It should be, in order to fetch all the remote tracking braches, including `origin/feature/xxx`:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note:

The Git plugin fetches branches and then look for the HEAD commit to checkout, which means it puts the repository in a [detached HEAD state](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/227266408-Current-Git-branch-is-HEAD-detached-at): it switch to a commit, not a branch itself.
Maybe that commit was laready part of a previous build.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68948600/jenkins-says-it-cant-find-git-branch-but-it-clearly-exists#comment121855835_68948766) below by [iftimie-tudor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7103406/iftimie-tudor), try and tweak the branch field:

```
feature/show-percentage-of-completion 
# or
*/show-percentage-of-completion
```

Comment: is this an error on the configuration page where the branch is */feature/show-percentage-of-completion, or the plugin line in the Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @Woodsman I wouldn't say for the Jenkinsfile, but if, on your job page, you have as "branch" "`*/feature/show-percentage-of-completion`" that should work (unless there is a typo). Check the refspecfield.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you check my attached screenshot?

Comment: for me it works with feature/show-percentage-of-completion or just */show-percentage-of-completion

Comment: @VonC I tried both feature/show-percentage-of-completion and */show-percentage-of-completion. Both don't work.

Comment: @Woodsman Could you try with other branches (with simpler names), just for testing if the issue is for all branches, or just this branch?

Comment: this worked. thanks!